# Xamarin Forms Image control allocating more height than requested

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm setting an explicit `HeightRequest` of `16` to my `Image` element; however, when debugging, the actual `Height` appears to have jumped to `70`. Here's my Xaml:

```
<Grid Margin="1" Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" HeightRequest="17">
    <BoxView CornerRadius="3" Color="LightGray"/>
    <BoxView Margin="1" CornerRadius="3" BackgroundColor="White"/>
    <StackLayout Margin="2,0,2,0" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="17" Spacing="0">
        <Image Source="hooray_icon"
               WidthRequest="16"
               HeightRequest="16"
               Margin="1,0,1,0"
               Aspect="Fill"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding HoorayCount}"
               Margin="1,0,1,0"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               HeightRequest="16"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Expected design:

[image: Expected]

Actual design:

[image: Actual]

*`hooray_icon` is a 512x512 PNG image.*

Xamarin.Forms version: `3.6.0.293080`

*P.S I knew it was the `Image` element that was causing the problem by using `class CustomImage : Image` and overriding and debugging `OnMeasure` and `OnSizeAllocated` methods. Correct me if I was mistaken.*

Comment: Can you try Aspect with "AspectFill" or "AspectFit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

`HeightRequest` is not guaranteed, it's just a request. If Xamarin.Forms is able to meet the request, it will implement it, but depending on screensize and layout, it may not be able to meet the request.

### Solution

Set the value of [`Grid.ColumnDefinition`'s `Width` and the `Grid.RowDefinition`'s `Height`](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin#rows-and-columns).

### Code

```
<Grid Margin="1" Padding="0" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="17" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <BoxView CornerRadius="3" Color="LightGray" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <BoxView Margin="1" CornerRadius="3" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <StackLayout Margin="2,0,2,0" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
        <Image Source="hooray_icon"
               Margin="1,0,1,0"
               Aspect="Fill"
               HeightRequest="16"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding HoorayCount}"
               Margin="1,0,1,0"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               HeightRequest="16"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I understand it's just a request. It's that I wasn't able to figure out why couldn't it be met. That solution, however, works it out. Thank you.